# angular 8 flex-layout 8 error : has no exported member ɵNgClassImpl error

Tags: angular, npm

I Have angular 8 project and tried to install flex-layout 8.0.0-beta.26.
I get this error on build.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/class/class.d.ts(9,19): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgClassImpl'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/class/class.d.ts(9,33): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgClassR2Impl'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(9,19): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgStyleImpl'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(9,33): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgStyleR2Impl'.
```

his is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

Can any one explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command :

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24
```